# Logisim: Implementing a control unit for "Addition", "Logic bitwise AND" and "right logic shift" in ALU

Tags: digital-logic, cpu, computer-architecture, alu, logisim

I'm very new to circuit design. I've built an ALU and now I only need a control unit for three operations, "Addition", "Logic bitwise AND" and "right logic shift". What is the most efficient way(least number of additional components) to do that on my current design?

My ALU.
[image]

My other instinct is to find a control unit out there and connect it with this ALU some how but I feel is over kill and struggling with it:  [How do I pass the 4 bit memory address back to my instruction Instruction address register and pass that data within memory into a register](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/573385/how-do-i-pass-the-4-bit-memory-address-back-to-my-instruction-instruction-addres?noredirect=1#comment1501841_573385)

I'd much rather not go this direction implementing RAM and multiple instruction register if I can do it efficiently to achieve a control unit that can achieve the 3 operations. Can someone show me how?

Comment: It's possible (I've not explored the idea with your instruction set) that you may be able to improve the situation a bit if you are willing to modify the opcode binary values. Is that an option for you? Or is that baked into the design, already? For example, if there is only a single bit difference between ADD and SUB, that bit can be used (and probably gated by other logic) at the ALU to invert the input and carry-in sense.

Comment: But... by way of an example, here is a [sample instruction decoder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Ufu.png) taken from Neeman's DIGITAL examples directory. Note the "ROM" there?

Comment: It is a bad idea to ask for the "most efficient" solution...engineers usually define their **requirements** and look for a solution that is "good enough". Also, you need to define what you mean by "efficient". Gate count? Transistor Count? Delay time? Clock speed? Silicon area? Design time?

Comment: ElliotAlderson, sorry efficient in this context is the least number of steps to get the three working instructions into a control unit that interacts with this ALU. 

@jonk, So what you're saying is, "Opcode > Mux > RAM > Opcode for ALU"? it does make sense to use another MUX. //// Thanks for the bit tip too will definitely consider it! I just placed it in order of the original requirement which lists addition, increments, followed by the rest. Subtraction was out of scope and something I added in for fun.

Comment: @nvs0000 Did the diagram make sense to you? You just use a ROM to decode out all the control signals required. If you need a sequence of control signals (say, four clocks per instruction and different control signals for each clock) then you include two added bits for addressing the ROM which are based upon a 2-bit FF counter tied to the clock.

Comment: I thought i did @jonk, but I think I'm abit lost, how do I input a line of instruction?

Comment: @nvs0000 Perhaps I assumed too much when reading your question. Do you have any memory in your simulation that can hold a program for you? You know, like 100 instructions for computing successive Fibonacci sequence numbers? Something like that? Or haven't you solved that problem, yet?

Comment: @jonk, sorry yea it's probably my fault. I'm just trying to be able to input a list of instructions and for the control unit to execute them. The original assignment question is as follows:  

"you are required to use Logisim to implement the control unit for at least the following three operations: 'addition, logic bitwise AND, right logic shift.' 
In order to finish this phase, you need to add operand registers according to the decision you took for the number of operands in phase two and, if needed, a flag register." So I'm just looking for the way to do so with the least amount of steps

Comment: We are not going to do your schoolwork for you, it's as simple as that. You must show us that you have made a serious effort to do this yourself, and I don't mean pulling random stuff from YouTube. When you have something that is close to working, ask a **specific** question.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, I don't think it's fair saying I haven't made a serious effort.. I've spent days trying to build a Control unit that works with my ALU - see the orange box. // In Q2, I've tried doing another way, by rebuilding a Youtube Control unit on Logisim to try and understand it better but it doesn't work because i suspect there's issues with the MUX, but cannot figure out what.

Comment: I'm afraid that you need a _concept_ or _architecture_ before trying stuff in Logisim. These are different levels of abstraction. Your course should also have given you enough concepts to solve this, perhaps you need to repeat earlier stuff. -- Some YouTube videos are plain wrong or misleading, I would not spend too much time with them. What did your non-YouTube web research reveal? Did you find for example "nand2tetris"?

Comment: 'Doesn't work', 'some issues' are not technical terms. Your question is poorly presented and it lacks specificity, I am afraid putting a bounty is not going to change that fact.

Comment: I agree with what Mitu says, you need to add more details on the problem you are facing, then I can try to help you better

Comment: @nvs0000 if you have a design question, we can answer that. Questions that ask for help with academics need to show a solution to the problem. Questions that ask for resources are generally off topic

Comment: The question was initially very simple, "what is the most efficient way(least components) to add a control unit that does addition, logic bitwise AND, and right logic shift?"

 // but comments in this thread asking me to show I did do a serious effort made me become more transparent with my workings, which clearly is a wrong steer.

Answer (score 1):

From the questions you ask, it looks like you have an idea how to do logic design, but you are struggling to connect it together. You could use a different design methodology to get better results. You are using a bottom-up methodology, that does not seem to scale up for you. So I advise you to use a top-down methodology instead.

Create a block diagram of the CPU first. Sketch the datapath and then identify the control signals. Create a truth table and design the control unit. Once that is complete, you can connect the ALU you built to your control unit.

Learn how a CPU works first, if you don't already know. I can recommend this free online course on Computer Architecture to get a sound understanding of how a CPU works: https://learn.saylor.org/course/view.php?id=71

If your demux or counter is not working, I would suggest to check if all your input signals are driven. From the figure you have posted, it looks like you have a few unconnected inputs.

Comment: I tried going specific and even rephrasing, but it seems like it needs more context as well. All i'm trying to nail down here is how to pass the memory address back into RAM: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/573385/how-do-i-pass-the-4-bit-memory-address-back-to-my-instruction-instruction-addres?noredirect=1#comment1501841_573385
/// Are you able to help?

Comment: @nvs0000 looks like a user busybee has already helped you by writing a useful comment on your question. Start by thinking over the comments you get.

Comment: @nvs0000 no, it's not so simple. You are asking "does this control unit work with my ALU" - This question hints at a lack of understanding of how CPU design works. You need to do a block diagram first.

Comment: thanks. I don't know if I'm overkilling for this question or not. It's worth only 5%, which is why I asked for the most efficient way to implement a control unit that performs addition, logic bitwise AND, and right logic shift per requirement. I've struggled with it for weeks now. Every other way I see requires building an entire control unit with RAM. Does a control unit technically need RAM?...

Comment: @nvs0000 You need instruction memory. RAM is used to store the program

Comment: Is there no way to build one without RAM? If so then my struggle correctly defined, the part where I can't get memory address back into RAM...?

Comment: You need RAM to run your program @nvs0000 Of course you can directly issue instructions to the decoder, that would be harder. I would suggest you clarify with your professor what exactly you are expected to build