# How do I pass the 4 bit memory address back to my RAM address input?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit, logisim

I'm trying to build a control unit. I'd like to pass the 4 bit memory back into my RAM.

I added an extender to get 8 bits, but something seems wrong with the circuit(in red), and from the feedback from comment, I'd need a sequencer.
[image]
[image]

Will this sequencer work? I never had a lesson about sequencer. Otherwise please show me a better sequencer to pass that 4 bit back into RAM?

[image]

The blueprints i'm building from below (open to receive a better one!)

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your understanding of how the simulator works, not an actual engineering problem. Though you do have two drivers on that red line; you need some sort of bus transciever there.

Comment: Thanks @hearth, are there people who can help us with Logisim here? I think it'd be really hard to implement a transceiver on Logisim. When you say "drivers" do you mean the "bit extender" vs the "Instruction Address Register"? Is there anyway to put some kind of a gate between them to have it pick one instead of the other?

Comment: That's what I mean by a bus transciever. I don't know the first thing about logisim, but if you have a bus that needs to have multiple drivers at different times, you need bus transcievers. If you have a bus that needs to have multiple drivers at the same time, you're doing something very wrong.

Comment: Any clue on how to build one?

Comment: You'd normally use a 74xx245.

Comment: Gosh it seems like an overkill to build that just so we can move the 4 bit memory address.

Comment: You'd normally buy one, not build it. At least if you're doing a Ben Eater style breadboard computer.

Comment: You have two outputs wired together, that will not work, neither in reality nor in the simulator. -- You need to rethink your design. How do you differentiate which of both outputs is presented to the memory? You might need a sequencer, which in turn controls a multiplexer. Other solutions are possible.

Comment: Would this sequencer be connected to the clock, which switches which source it selects? (Ie. Instruction address register vs Memory address)// Should memory address feed in on the down tick and the instruction address register move on the up tick? Would a sequencer like this work: https://imgur.com/a/nUQwZw5 ?

Comment: Sorry @thebusybee, i realized the imgur link doesn't work, have added it to the question now and thanks for helping me narrow down my question, now I just need to know how to build a sequencer into my circuit, are you able to help?

Comment: Hm, it seems as if you're a toddler and want to learn how to do long jumps. ;-) Are you sure this is an appropriate task for you now? Please note that SE/EE is a Q&A site, we cannot teach you but with concrete answers to specific questions. If you are following a course, you should have enough in your lectures to solve the issue. Else I suggest to step back and to learn the basics.

Comment: All I need is to understand how to pass that those memory bits back into the RAM, that should be specific enough..? Would love if you're able to help me there(Orange circle) with your big boy/girl grown up skills.

Answer (score 1):

The blueprints seems, the assignment is to build a sequencer/processor or something like that(?) Then, the part you are working on is generating address with offset from an instruction (0x20) for the next fetch cycle ([addr + offset[4]).

1. Latch the "DATA" of the current cycle to use at the next fetch cycle.
2. IF(Latched OPCODE[7:4] == 0b0010), then disable WRITE_ENABLE, enable READ_ENABLE. This is in the logic gates of the blueprint. However, the WRITE ENABLE signal line needs some touch in the drawing, don't connect together.
3. IF(Latched OPCODE[7:4] == 0b0010), then regenerate the memory(RAM) address, ADDRESS_INPUT + Latched OPCODE[3:0], which is the offset, which is 0b1110 in the blueprint. While doing the addition, you need to consider if the offset is relative in both direction (+/-). If so, the effective bits of the offset become [2:0], and bit[3] could be the sign bit.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding @jay I'm trying to build a control unit out of the blue print i saw from here: https://youtu.be/FZGugFqdr60?t=230 . If I'm reading you right, you are saying the blue print is wrong? Would you mind showing me even with a crude drawing how point 2 is it suppose to connect? // I'm also not at a place where I can understand what "OPCODE[7:4] = 0b0010" mean. Am I right to assuming you're referring to a register, and if you don't mind would you please stating it in binary?

Comment: I also added a simpler version, used 0000 0001 so the explanation doesn't confuse me and marked out the question very specifically in drawing to state the question i need answered.

Comment: I see what that is, @nvs0000. It is an inspiring clip, reminding me many. In my opinion, the video could be better as an introductory material. I would recommend these as well: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine" "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture", "https://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2020/1/241712-von-neumann-thought-turings-universal-machine-was-simple-and-neat/fulltext". .. this is cutting short, will continue.

Comment: @nvs0000, I've started, and should try to complete or be completed. However, I do not think it can be accomplished through stackexchange. Please read these as well, and let me know your thoughts: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture", "https://geteducationskills.com/computer-architecture/".

Comment: @nvs0000, These (and logic components) are the supporting materials under the "architecture": , "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_logic", "https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/sequential/seq_1.html".